# Why they use bit shift operator? OSdev

Tags: c, operating-system

I want to learn something new about opearting systems so I decided to take a look at OSdev wiki webpage. I dont have any idea why they use bit shift operator in **vga_entry_color** and in **vga_entry** function. Can somebody tell me why they used this?

You can find this code on:
https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones#Writing_a_kernel_in_C

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
/* Check if the compiler thinks you are targeting the wrong operating system. */
#if defined(__linux__)
#error "You are not using a cross-compiler, you will most certainly run into trouble"
#endif
 
/* This tutorial will only work for the 32-bit ix86 targets. */
#if !defined(__i386__)
#error "This tutorial needs to be compiled with a ix86-elf compiler"
#endif
 
/* Hardware text mode color constants. */
enum vga_color {
    VGA_COLOR_BLACK = 0,
    VGA_COLOR_BLUE = 1,
    VGA_COLOR_GREEN = 2,
    VGA_COLOR_CYAN = 3,
    VGA_COLOR_RED = 4,
    VGA_COLOR_MAGENTA = 5,
    VGA_COLOR_BROWN = 6,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREY = 7,
    VGA_COLOR_DARK_GREY = 8,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE = 9,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN = 10,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN = 11,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_RED = 12,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_MAGENTA = 13,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_BROWN = 14,
    VGA_COLOR_WHITE = 15,
};
 
static inline uint8_t **vga_entry_color**(enum vga_color fg, enum vga_color bg) 
{
    return fg | bg << 4;
}
 
static inline uint16_t **vga_entry**(unsigned char uc, uint8_t color) 
{
    return (uint16_t) uc | (uint16_t) color << 8;
}
 
size_t strlen(const char* str) 
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while (str[len])
        len++;
    return len;
}
 
static const size_t VGA_WIDTH = 80;
static const size_t VGA_HEIGHT = 25;
 
size_t terminal_row;
size_t terminal_column;
uint8_t terminal_color;
uint16_t* terminal_buffer;
 
void terminal_initialize(void) 
{
    terminal_row = 0;
    terminal_column = 0;
    terminal_color = vga_entry_color(VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREY, VGA_COLOR_BLACK);
    terminal_buffer = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
    for (size_t y = 0; y < VGA_HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++) {
            const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
            terminal_buffer[index] = vga_entry(' ', terminal_color);
        }
    }
}
 
void terminal_setcolor(uint8_t color) 
{
    terminal_color = color;
}
 
void terminal_putentryat(char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y) 
{
    const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
    terminal_buffer[index] = vga_entry(c, color);
}
 
void terminal_putchar(char c) 
{
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if (++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH) {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if (++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT)
            terminal_row = 0;
    }
}
 
void terminal_write(const char* data, size_t size) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        terminal_putchar(data[i]);
}
 
void terminal_writestring(const char* data) 
{
    terminal_write(data, strlen(data));
}
 
void kernel_main(void) 
{
    /* Initialize terminal interface */
    terminal_initialize();
 
    /* Newline support is left as an exercise. */
    terminal_writestring("Hello, kernel World!\n");
}
```

Comment: Looks like foreground and background colors for a VGA text mode.

Comment: The four foreground bits are held in b0..3 and the four background bits are in b4..7. These are used by the hardware to lookup the palette table entries, which  in a similar way use 8 bits in a 16-bit value to define the *actual* colours.

Comment: In a more general vein, please note the existence of [the OSDev Forum](https://forum.osdev.org) where questions regarding the OSDev wiki are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static inline uint8_t vga_entry_color(enum vga_color fg, enum vga_color bg) 
{
    return fg | bg << 4;
}
```

This takes a 4-bit foreground color `ffff` and a 4-bit background color `bbbb` and returns it as a single 8-bit number `bbbbffff`, with the bits jammed together.

```
static inline uint16_t vga_entry(unsigned char uc, uint8_t color) 
{
    return (uint16_t) uc | (uint16_t) color << 8;
}
```

This takes an 8-bit character `cccccccc` (`uc`) and an 8-bit color `CCCCCCCC` and returns it as a single 16-bit number `CCCCCCCCcccccccc`, with the bits jammed together.  So since the color number `CCCCCCCC` came from `vga_entry_color`, you'd end up with `bbbbffffcccccccc`, which as a comment from @DevSolar explains is the way that VGA text mode expects things.

This is all similar to the way, in decimal, if I ask you to take the digits `3` and `4` and stick them together to form a new number, you can do `10 × 3 + 4 = 34`, and if I ask you to take the numbers `12` and `34`and stick them together to form a new number, you can do `100 × 12 + 34 = 1234`.

In binary, shifting left by a bit is equivalent to multiplying by 2.  This is equivalent to the fact that in decimal, multiplying by 10 is equivalent to tacking on a `0` at the right and shifting everything left by a digit: `5 × 10 = 50`.  So in binary, shifting left by N bits is equivalent to multiplying by 2<sup>N</sup>, and in many cases, shifting right by N bits is equivalent to dividing by 2<sup>N</sup>.

(For this reason, some people will tell you that if you're multiplying or dividing by a power of two, you should use bit shifts instead, to make your code "more efficient".  This might still be true in some cases, but it's generally misleading advice.  Modern processors are so fast that simple multiplications and divisions might not be measurably slower than simple bit shifts.  And if the bit shifts are faster, your compiler is probably smart enough to make the substitutions itself.  Finally, if you're working with negative numbers, it turns out that the bit shifts can give slightly different results.)

Comment: ...and this is necessary because that's the way VGA text mode expects it. Note that the tutorial mentions VGA text mode being deprecated and modern UEFI systems no longer supporting it.