# How does 10 separate the digits in n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0')?

Tags: c, type-conversion, integer-arithmetic

This function converts a string of digits into its numeric equivalent:

```
int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n;

    n = 0;
    for ( i = 0 ; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9' ; ++i )
    {
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    }
    return n;
}
```

My question is about this line -> `n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');`

particularly this part `10 * n`. I don't understand the way 10 effects the execution. If I remove it, the expression just sums the digits up. I don't understand how 10 separates the digits by multiplying 0.

Comment: Say the # is 123. First iteration, it finds 0*10+1 (1), second iteration it finds 1 (previous result)*10+2 (12), last iteration 12 (previous result)*10+3 (123). The *10 just multiplies the previous digits calculated by 10 before adding the current digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the number 1234.  It is made up of the digits 1, 2, 3, and 4.  If you receive this digits in that order, you can build the original number step by step:

```
n = 1
n = 1 * 10 + 2 = 12
n = 12 * 10 + 3 = 123
n = 123 * 10 + 4 = 1234
```

Putting it into one equation:

```
n = ((((1 * 10) + 2) * 10) + 3) * 10 + 4
  = ((1 * 10 * 10 + 2 * 10) + 3) * 10 + 4
  = 1 * 10 * 10 * 10 + 2 * 10 * 10 + 3 * 10 + 4
  = 1 * 1000 + 2 * 100 + 3 * 10 + 4
  = 1000 + 200 + 30 + 4
  = 1234
```

So the first digits get multiplied by more 10's than the later digits.  It is merely distributing the powers of 10 by multiplying by them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number like for example `1234` then it can be obtained like the result of the expression

```
( ( ( ( 0 ) * 10  + 1 ) * 10 + 2 ) * 10 + 3 ) * 10 + 4
```

If digits are stored as character symbols as for example '3' then to obtain the numeric digit `3` you can write `'3' - '0'`.

Pay attention to that the shown function will not work when the passed string contains a negative number or when a number starts with the sign '+'.

Also its parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const` because the passed string is not changed in the function.

```
int atoi( const char s[] );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was just writing in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68376217/why-they-use-bit-shift-operator-osdev/68376760#68376760), if I ask you to take the digits `3` and `4` and stick them together to form a new number, you can do `10 × 3 + 4 = 34`, and if I ask you to take the numbers `12` and `34` and stick them together to form a new number, you can do `100 × 12 + 34 = 1234`.

Multiplying by 10 is equivalent to tacking on a 0 at the right and shifting everything left by a digit: `3 × 10 = 30`. Similarly, multiplying by 100 is equivalent to tacking on two 0's at the right and shifting everything left by two digits: `12 × 100 = 1200`.

Answer (score 0):

In base 10 every additional digit increases the value of the digits on the left 10 fold.